# What actually happens when we open a connection to the file while creating a stream object?

Tags: java, java-io

Say when I write,

```
InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("LOCATION");
```

So what happens with the `new FileInputStream("LOCATION")` part?

I read materials on the web stating it opens a connection to this location. So by *"opening a connection"* should I assume that it's bringing entire data from `"LOCATION"` into the `inStream`?

And if it is not bringing the entire data then what it does?

Comment: io stream is just an abstraction to allow sequential read/write of the resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, definitely not. It opens a channel that allows you to read data. But as long as you don't do actual reading it doesn't bring any data up. Note that once you opened a Stream you are required to close it. otherwise a memory leak may occur. That's why you usually surround your opening streams in try - catch block

Comment: Thanks! That helped.

Answer (score 2):

It just creates a connection to the file at that location.It does not bringing data at that time.

To get any data you have to invoke read method which gets the data in packets.